# predict() leaving out values instead of giving NA

Tags: r, predictive-models, missing-data

I'm using predict on my random forest and nnet model and there will be a few values missing from the final predictions.

```
predict(psm_list_item$pmod, test_pac, type = 'prob')$yes

i=which(is.na(psm_pred))
return(data.frame(pred=psm_pred[-i], truth=psm_truth[-i]))
```

This does not work because the length of psm_pred is 6744 but the labels/truth is length 6748. I don't know if there's a way to match up the predicted probabilities with the truth this way, because it could be any 4 in the truth that could correspond to the missing predictions. Has anyone dealt with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `nnet` supports the all the standard `na.action` arguments. So, you can set `na.action = na.exclude` in the `nnet` call. Then `predict` will insert NAs into the predicted values at the appropriate places and your code should work.

Alternatively, you could try something like

```
i = which(is.na(df))
return(data.frame(pred=psm_pred,truth=psm_truth[-i]))
```

(assuming I've read your code correctly) which would exclude the true values from rows with missing data, and leave only the predictions and truth from the complete cases.